# Building a drag and drop puzzle-type interface with snap alignment

Tags: java, android, alignment, snapping

I'm building an Android puzzle game where the user rotates and shifts pieces of a puzzle to form a final picture. It's a bit like a sliding block puzzle but the shape and size of pieces is not uniform - more like a sliding block version of tetris.

At the moment I've got puzzle pieces as imageViews which can be selected and moved around a view to position them. I've got the vector forms of the shapes behind the scenes as ArrayLists of Points.

But...I'm stuck on how to snap align the pieces together. I.e. when a piece is nearby another, shift one piece so that the nearby edges overlay each other (i.e. essentially share a boundary).

I'm sure this has been done plenty of times but can't find examples with code (in any language). It's similar to snapping to a grid but not the same and is the same kind of functionality you get in a diagramming type interface when you can snap objects to each other.

Can anyone point me toward a tutorial (any langauge) / code / or advise on how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Urs is like Tangram game. I think it cannot be done with pieces of image to form a final picture. It can be done by Creating Geometry shapes(for both Final shape and pieces/slices of final picture) using android.Graphics package. Its quite easy to determine the final shape from the edges and vertices of pieces/slices.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/photogaffe/ is worth checking out. It is an opensource sliding puzzle consisting of 15 pieces and allows the user to choose an image from their gallery.

You would only have to figure out your various shapes and how to rotate them. And if you are supplying your own images...how to load them.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

What about drawing a box around each shape. Afterwards you define the middle of it. Then you can store a value for the rotation for each piece. And you would need to store the neighbours together with a vector the their middle.

Then you simply have to compute that the vector is in a reasonable range and the rotation is +-X degree. For example if the vector is in a range of +-10pixels and the rotation is +-3° you could rotate the piece and fit it into the puzzle.